# Could not find artifact in maven local repository

Tags: java, android, maven

I installed external jars into maven local repositories via maven android sdk deployer successfully.
Because these are not available into maven central repositories.

```
Failed to execute goal on project mavendemo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mavendemo:mavendemo:apk:1.0: **The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.square:picasso:jar:1.0, com.analytics-androids-1.0.0:analytics-android.1.0.0:jar:1.0.0, com.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4, com.scribe:scribe:jar:1.0:** **Could not find artifact com.square:picasso:jar:1.0 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)** -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want builds to work on other systems you need to set up a repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory.  I'm guessing that's what you want, though you didn't actually ask a question.